# Undefined function putText in Netbeans using c++ with OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, opencv3.0

I'm trying to configure my Netbeans to use OpenCV 3.0.0,

When I try to build my project I got this message:

> undefined reference to `cv::putText(cv::*InputOutputArray const&, cv::String const&, cv::Point*, int, double, cv::Scalar_, int, int, bool)'

These are my includes:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

and my linker config:

```
additional libraries ---> C:/OpenCV/release/lib

libraries ---> C:/OpenCV/release/lib/libopencv_core300.dll.a , 
               C:/OpenCV/release/lib/libopencv_highgui300.dll.a
```

Netbeans version 8.0.2, OpenCV version 3.0.0

I've compiled my own OpenCV with cmake-gui ( mingw ).

Comment: You need to add to your linker also libopencv_imgproc300.dll.a. (BTW your second #include in useless)

Comment: so how can i see which dll is required by each function??

Comment: In the documentation